# Python code to loop through a list which has 2 variables per cycle

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to understand how to add in a 2 variable list and have the python code cycle through it like with a loop

for example

[[1, 9], [2, 9], [3, 7],[4. 6],[5, 9],[6, 9]]

in the example below its 
`12,9`    where 12 would be used to populate M and it would iterate through the code 9 times so making length = 9 then move onto the next iteration for 2,9 after it had finished etc

```
#This is how many iterations are needed
  list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]


# Getting length of list 
   length = len(list) 
   i = 0

   # Iterating using while loop 
     while i < length: 

   #This is the ID    
     m = '12'
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean, and remove useless parts of the code? It would help if you provided the expected output

Comment: Cheers Nicolas .. I'm just trying to understand can I feed in a list and loop based on two variables ... at the moment it's doing it on 1 the list length but each item will have a list lengh and an additional value... so basically a pair of values ...

Comment: I'm willing to help, I'm sure I can find a solution. However, I can't understand your question and by the absence of answers I can tell no one else understood. I suggest you include your expected output, and also format your list properly, e.g., `[[1, 9], [2, 9]]`

Comment: Cheers Nicolas, I think thats helped alot, I didnt realise thats how the list would have to be formated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
mylist = [[1, 9], [2, 9], [3, 7], [4, 6], [5, 9], [6, 9]]

for first, second in mylist:
    M = first
    for i in range(second):
        print(f'The ID is {M}, iteration number {i}')
```

```
The ID is 1, iteration number 0
The ID is 1, iteration number 1
The ID is 1, iteration number 2
The ID is 1, iteration number 3
The ID is 1, iteration number 4
The ID is 1, iteration number 5
The ID is 1, iteration number 6
The ID is 1, iteration number 7
The ID is 1, iteration number 8
The ID is 2, iteration number 0
The ID is 2, iteration number 1
The ID is 2, iteration number 2
The ID is 2, iteration number 3
...
```

Comment: Fantastic Nicolas, that worked perfectly,   thank you so much for taking the time out to help , the part that was very valuable was the list and having how to structure it for the two values. Super thankful mate.